# When and why does mating make you unhappy?

Tags: fallout-shelter

... not *you,* that is, but your dwellers.

Normally, when "magic happens" between a male and a female dweller in the living quarters, happiness of the both of them soars (usually going to 100%). However, twice now, I have actually had the woman's happiness drop to 10% as she became pregnant. It recovered eventually, but it's still a curious occurence. I generally try to keep my dwellers happy, so this was a nasty surprise.

Is there a way to predict when this will happen, and prevent it?

Comment: I can say I've never had that happen. Was there some kind of incident in the vault at the time?

Comment: @DCShannon I don't know, it didn't occur to me to check. I will definitely keep an eye out for this if it happens next time.

Comment: Maybe she just didn't want to have any more kids...

Answer (score 2):

**If the health of a dweller is very low, his/her happiness gradually drops to 10%. In this case, mating doesn't increase the dweller's happiness.** *(Personal experience)*
Try giving a Stimpak/Radaway to the unhappy dweller. It should really help, and your dweller should be able to be happy again.